# Azure data factory linked service for GoogleBigQuery

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am using Azure Data Factory to build a pipeline using GoogleBigQuery and have created the linked service for the same accordingly and tested the connection successfully. For some reason I see no tables in the Table dropdown. What am I missing?

[image: ADF]

Answer (score 1):

Would recommend to check the IAM policy for the creds used in linked service for BQ.

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/table-access-controls-intro) You can check the access controls for the creds.

[Here is Example](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/table-access-controls-intro#example_use_case)